# Severely truncated attribute while compiling JavaFX Undertow Websockets project for Android with jfxmobile-plugin

Tags: javafx, websocket, undertow, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I am having an issue while compiling my JavaFX project for Android.
The project includes a bunch of libraries, Undertow Websockets is among them. I downloaded all required jars to my lib directory and included them into dependencies / compile files block of build.gradle file.

I was able to solve other issues with jar-files dependencies (mostly DuplicateFileException), but one Undertow library - **undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar** gives me a little bit of a headache.

When I add it to *compile file* block of gradle.build file ‘gradlew android’ gives me an error message:

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ‘:createMainDexList’.
>
> Exception in thread “main” com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException:
>   severely truncated attribute at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.StdAttributeFactory.throwSeverelyTruncated(StdAttributeFactory.java:736)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.StdAttributeFactory.runtimeVisibleParameterAnnotations(StdAttributeFactory.java:661)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.StdAttributeFactory.parse0(StdAttributeFactory.java:162)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeFactory.parse(AttributeFactory.java:96)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.parse(AttributeListParser.java:141)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.parseIfNecessary(AttributeListParser.java:115)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.AttributeListParser.getEndOffset(AttributeListParser.java:96)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parse(MemberListParser.java:213)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parseIfNecessary(MemberListParser.java:108)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.MethodListParser.getList(MethodListParser.java:54)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:542)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToEndIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:397)
>   at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getAttributes(DirectClassFile.java:311)
>   at
>   com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.hasRuntimeVisibleAnnotation(MainDexListBuilder.java:191)
>   at
>   com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.keepAnnotated(MainDexListBuilder.java:167)
>   at
>   com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.(MainDexListBuilder.java:121)
>   at
>   com.android.multidex.MainDexListBuilder.main(MainDexListBuilder.java:91)
>   at
>   com.android.multidex.ClassReferenceListBuilder.main(ClassReferenceListBuilder.java:58)
>   …while parsing RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations attribute at offset 0009c07 > …while parsing attributes[3] 
>   …while parsing methods[1] 
>   …while parsing io/undertow/client/http/HttpResponseParser$$generated.class

Below is my build.gradle file contents:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10'
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'          

    }       
}


apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

apply plugin: 'java'  
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8  
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.simlayserstudio.SimlayserStudio'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
//        compileSdkVersion = 16 // version 4.2.1
        compileSdkVersion = 23 // version 6
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/io.undertow.attribute.ExchangeAttributeBuilder'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/io.undertow.predicate.PredicateBuilder'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/io.undertow.server.handlers.builder.HandlerBuilder'
            //exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'

        }
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}

dependencies {      

        compile  ('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10',
                  'commons-io:commons-io:2.4',
                  'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6',
//                  'io.undertow:undertow-servlet:1.3.14.Final' // Duplicate zip entry [allclasses.jar:javax/annotation/Generated.class
            )

    compile files(           
        '/lib/jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar', //ok wtih exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
//        '/lib/undertow-core-1.3.14.Final.jar', // ERROR com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: severely truncated attribute
        '/lib/undertow-servlet-1.3.14.Final.jar', // ok wtih exclude ExchangeAttributeBuilder, PredicateBuilder, HandlerBuilder     
        '/lib/undertow-websockets-jsr-1.3.14.Final.jar', //ok with  exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        '/lib/xnio-api-3.3.4.Final.jar', //ok with  exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        '/lib/xnio-nio-3.3.4.Final.jar', //ok with  exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

        '/lib/apache-commons.jar',        //ok
        '/lib/com.thoughtworks.xstream.jar', //ok                         
        '/lib/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar', //ok
        '/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar',  //ok              
        '/lib/xmlpull-xpp3-1.1.4c.jar', //ok
    )    


}
```

Did anybody manage generating apk with Undertow Websockets, or encounter similar issues with 3-rd party libraries?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to reproduce the same error you've posted, just by using this dependencies and running `./gradlew android`:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('io.undertow:undertow-servlet:1.3.19.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation' 
    }
    compile ('io.undertow:undertow-core:1.3.19.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation' 
    }
    compile ('io.undertow:undertow-websockets-jsr:1.3.19.Final') {
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation' 
    }
}
```

So in order to find out about the possible issue, I've downloaded the io.undertow` sources from [here](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/releases/tag/1.3.19.Final), added the required dependencies (maybe I'm not using the exact versions):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:2.0.1.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.classfilewriter:jboss-classfilewriter:1.0.4.Final'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.alpn:alpn-api:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.jboss.xnio:xnio-nio:3.3.4.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.xnio:xnio-api:3.3.4.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket:jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:1.0.0.Final'
}
```

And to avoid duplicated classes from `javax.annotation`, I've downloaded the sources of `org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec` from [here](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-annotations-api_spec/archive/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.zip), and removed these three classes: `Generated.java`, `PostConstruct.java` and `PreDestroy.java`.

I was able to run `./gradlew android` successfully, but I haven't tested it.

In case you still have issues building it or later running it on the device, maybe you can consider other alternatives for websockets like the [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net) project.

This is a [project](https://github.com/TRIPJavaFXClientBraintrust/TRIPfx) were we have used it successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much José! That was exactly what I needed. I followed your steps and was able to generate the apk. Hooray! I did not have a chance to deploy and run it yet, but at least the compilation is working now. Thank you for your advice to consider alternatives for websockets.  I will definitely have a look.